# How to align multiple textbox horizontally after label under form-group in bootstrap-3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to align multiple textbox horizontally after label under form-group in bootstrap-3
my output is

[image]

But I want to get output like

[image]

I have try with this code

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="mobile" >Mobile</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control isd-code" name="mobile[]" placeholder="88">
     <span class="dash"> - </span>
     <input type="text" class="form-control mobile" name="mobile[]" placeholder="Enter Name">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [Bootstrap's Inline Forms documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline), you need to firstly give your `form` element a class of "form-inline":

```
<form class="form inline" ... >
```

Then wrap each individual inline form element within a `.form-group` container:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="mobile" >Mobile</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control isd-code" name="mobile[]" placeholder="88">
</div>
<span class="dash"> - </span>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control mobile" name="mobile[]" placeholder="Enter Name">
</div>
```

Comment: when I apply this code then label text "mobile" also align horizontally. But I neet to keep lable like my image

Comment: @Md.SahadatHossain you can give your `label` a style of `display: block`.

Comment: Also, you can give the label a class of "col-xs-12", which will let it stretch across the entire width of the page - and then wrap the inputs in a div with its own class of "col-xs-12".